# SwiftUI - QGrid with static cells

Tags: gridview, swiftui, xcode11, macos-catalina

Im using this SwiftUI Package, that allows for Grids:
https://github.com/Q-Mobile/QGrid

Im trying to make a simple grid without data (static cells), but got the error bellow.

Xcode 11 Beta 5
Catalina Beta 5

[image]

My code:

```
import QGrid
import SwiftUI

struct GridView: View {
var body: some View {
QGrid(columns: 4, { ProductCell() }
}
}

#if DEBUG
struct GridView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
GridView()
}
}
#endif
```

Why am I getting such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the package to create a grid without data. If you look at its code, there is only one `QGrid` initializer, and it requires data.

Here's a minimal example:

```swift
import QGrid
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let array = [Item(name: "Name #1"), Item(name: "Name #2"), Item(name: "Name #3"), Item(name: "Name #4"), Item(name: "Name #5")]

    var body: some View {
        QGrid(array, columns: 3) { value in
            MyCell(item: value)
        }
    }
}

struct MyCell: View {
    let item: Item

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(item.name)")
    }
}
```

You may use a bogus array and ignore the data when drawing the cells. But do you need the package then? Also note that QGrid knows how many cells to draw, because of `array.count`.

This would be with a bogus array:

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable { let id = UUID() }

struct ContentView: View {
    let array = Array<Item>(repeating: Item(), count: 5)

    var body: some View {
        QGrid(array, columns: 3) { value in
            MyCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated to add a bogus array, as an example.

Comment: Thanks @kontiki! Will use your suggestion for now, and then change later when I have data structure setup.